# Could an unitialized pointer be a NULL pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, null, initialization

From what I have read a NULL pointer points to the memory location "0" and an unitialized pointer points to a random location? Could it be that this random location sometimes is the "0" so that it is a NULL pointer as well? I realize that this will not happen all the time, but could it happen? Or has C some mechanism to stop it from happening?

Comment: Uninitialized pointers may contain any random value, including 0. I'm not aware of any compiler that would guarantee the random value is not 0.

Comment: Short answer: When _declaring_ a pointer, or any other variable, **always** assign a known value to it. (Favour `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` for dynamic allocation.) Eschew declaring variables "that I'll remember to assign with a value later..." Develop good habits early on and save yourself countless (pointless) hours of bug-hunting. (I suspect, but can't say for sure, that modern compilers would optimise: `int x = 0; /*other stuff not touching x*/; x = 10;` to be effectively: `int x = 10;` There's no reason, and much danger, declaring only `int x;` and move on.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 `calloc()` would work for most implementations apart from some weird and rare implementations where an "all-bytes zero" pointer value does not represent a null pointer value.

Comment: @IanAbbott People who work with "_weird implementations_" have only themselves to blame... `:-)` Thanks for clarifying my rant... `:-)`

Comment: Mea culpa... `int x;` _defines_ the (uninitialised) variable `x`... `extern int x;` _declares_ (promises) the compiler that the linker will find a definition of `x` somewhere else at link time. Regardless, `char *ptr;`, all on its own somewhere, should evoke feelings of revulsion. It's an accident waiting to happen. (In summary, from-the-get-go, do not write code with unitialised variables. Your question becomes moot.)

Comment: It is sometimes difficult to tell valid pointers and null pointers apart. For example `(void *)0` is a null pointer constant but `(void *)(0, 0)` is not a null pointer constant, but the two values may have the same binary representation. Most implementations work around that by disallowing access to memory address 0, but that is not always possible.

Comment: [What's the difference between null pointers and NULL?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278657) Hopefully straightens out some misconceptions. Basically a null pointers contents could be anything, even if we assign a null pointer constant `0`. This is a special oddball thing in C. The upcoming C23 seeks to de-mystify it a bit by adding `nullptr` but I have yet to understand what problem that actually solves. C++ had it forever and nobody seems able to explain what difference it does. (C++ always had an all-zero representation for null pointers before C++11.)

Comment: @Lundin: AFAIUI, in C, defining `#define nullptr ((void *)0)` works because a void pointer can be converted to any other type without a cast.  In C++, that's not true; you can't convert a void pointer to any other type without an explicit cast.  Prior to the addition of `nullptr`, you had to write `(type *)0` or equivalent to create a pointer of the right type; with `nullptr`, you can simply use `nullptr` in place of that.  So, `nullptr` provides a major benefit in C++; it is a minor benefit in C.  Some systems (AIX!) still have `NULL` defined as `0` rather than a pointer type, despite POSIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could an unitialized pointer be a NULL pointer?

An uninitialized pointer could be a null pointer.

(Do not use “NULL” for a null pointer. `NULL` is a specific macro defined by standard C headers with some different implications.)

> From what I have read a NULL pointer points to the memory location "0"…

Many C implementations use memory address zero for null pointers, but this is not the only possibility. The C standard merely requires a null pointer to compare unequal to any object or function in the C program.

> … and an unitialized pointer points to a random location?

No, “random” is a [different concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness). Saying something is random is asserting there is a lack of pattern or predictability to it. While it would not violate the C standard for an uninitialized object to behave randomly, the C standard does not say it does that, and it is unlikely that an uninitialized object would actually behave randomly rather than having at least some pattern of behavior arising out of the programming environment, although not a pattern controlled by the C standard.

An uninitialized object is said to have an *indeterminate* value. An indeterminate value is not any particular value but is a description of how the object behaves. Effectively, it means the C standard does not require the object to have a determined value—in other words, the value is not fixed; it can appear to be different at different times—and does not require a C implementation to take the value from any particular place, including the memory reserved for the object.

This means that, during optimization, a compiler may take the value of the object from memory, from a processor register, or anywhere else, and it may use different sources at different times, and other aspects of the program or the environment may change whatever source or sources the program is using for the value. So the value of the object in the program may appear to change.

For example, if `a` is an uninitialized `int`, then `printf("%d\n", a); printf("%d\n", a);` could print two different numbers.

> Could it be that this random location sometimes is the "0" so that it is a NULL pointer as well?

It can happen that the value used for an indeterminate pointer is a null pointer.